# Default dataset for Core Data based iPhone application

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am writing an iPhone 3.0 application that uses Core Data to persist the model. I'd like the application to be installed with a default dataset. When developing for iPhone < 3.0 I used an SQL script to initialize a database prior to running a build and then deployed the prepared .sqlite file as an application resource. What's the best approach with Core Data.

**A conclusion:** In the end I wrote a generic XML handler. Element names are mapped to Objective-C class names and property names. PCDATA values within elements were converted into the type declared on the property named by the element. Child elements or property elements were resolved to object instances - and thus through parsing an XML document an object graph was built. I had to get to grips with the Objective-C runtime first though :-)

Example target classes:

```
@interface Widget : NSObject {
@private
    NSString* name;
    NSSet* sprockets;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* sprockets;
- (void)addSprocketsObject:(Sprocket*)value;    
@end

@interface Sprocket : NSObject {
@private
    NSString* name;
    NSNumber* canFly;
    NSNumber* wheels;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* canFly;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* wheels;
@end
```

Example default data:

```
<data>
    <Sprocket id="sprocket-1">
        <name>Sprocket1</name>
        <wheels>4</wheels>
    </Sprocket>
    <Widget id="widget-1">
        <name>MyWidget</name>
        <sprockets>
            <Sprocket ref-id="sprocket-1"/>
            <Sprocket id="sprocket-2">
                <name>Sprocket2</name>
                <canFly/>
            </Sprocket>
            <Sprocket id="sprocket-3">
                <name>Sprocket3</name>
            </Sprocket>
        </sprockets>
    </Widget>
</data>
```

Comment: I've been populating coredata databases on the first application run from plists, resulting in very long first run load times.  I keep seeing people say "use the pre-populated .sqlite databases that you generate in the application bundle".  The CoreData books example shows you how to use the .sqlite file once you've found it, but where is it in the first place?  I found the answer here:  http://ablogontech.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/using-a-pre-populated-sqlite-database-with-core-data-on-iphone-os-3-0/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options spring to mind:

1. Write an importer from some reasonable data format (XML, JSON, etc.) and import that into your Core Data context on first run, then save the context to a persistent store.
2. If your app only needs one persistent store, you can pre-populate it and deploy the persistent store with your app's resources. If you need multiple persistent stores, all pre-populated with the same default data, option 1 is probably going to be easier, but you could use NSPersistenStoreCoordinator's migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error: (or the equivalent in iPhone Core Data -- still  under NDA) to create the new store from the pre-poplated store for each new store needed.

In my experience the code to implement option 1 is nearly the same code as required to prepopulate a persistent store, so perhaps there's really only one option with two points of view.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Plist to store the initial data and populate your persistent store on first run.  This approach is easier than having to write your own custom XML parser.