# How can I use a pre-populated core data DB on my device

Tags: iphone, core-data, device

I have developed my app using core data.  It works fine in the simulator.  When I deploy it to the device the DB is empty. It is 49k where it should be 484k.

Basically it is not populated.  Since I don't write to the DB when the app is running I need to provide a populated DB to the App.  So I copied the populated DB from the simulator to resources and then deploy.

Still no luck.  the populated DB is in MyApp.app and the AppDelegate is reading from the Documents directory.  How do I either get it in the documents directory or get the app delegate to look in the app?

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question:
[Any way to pre populate core data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230354/any-way-to-pre-populate-core-data/2230417#2230417)