# Xcode 4 CoreData set data visually

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4

Im using xcode 4 and i've created a CoreData model. I would like to know if its possible to insert data into an entity within xcode.

Please don't tell me the only way to enter data into a model is programmatically.

Cheers

Comment: Do you like to prepopulate your database?

Comment: Yeh, i would like to set up and insert all the data into the database in xcode and then use that data in my program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not enter data directly with XCode. If you don't want to do this with code you can prepopulate your db. Have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230354/any-way-to-pre-populate-core-data) on SO.

Comment: Man Apple makes it hard. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Ray Wenderlich provides a tutorial on [How to Preload/Import Existing Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data) using a Python script to populate the database.

His three-part series on [Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very slow procedure, but you can populate Core Data.

Insert the following code in appDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   ...

    //test
    //writing data

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *model = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Invitados" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [model setValue:@"Alicia" forKey:@"name"];
        [model setValue:@"Sanchez" forKey:@"firstname"];
        [model setValue:@"Romero" forKey:@"secondname"];


        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        //retrieving data
        // NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        //NSError *error;

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"Invitados" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject *get in fetchedObjects) {
            NSLog(@"Nombre: %@", [get valueForKey:@"name"]);
            NSLog(@"Apellido 1: %@", [get valueForKey:@"firstname"]);
            NSLog(@"Apellido 2: %@",[get valueForKey:@"secondname"]);
        }
        // End test
```

Comment: How would you do this with Cocoa? Cocoa does not have `NSFetchRequestController` but instead uses the `NSArrayController`