# CoreData Model Not Retrieving the Attribute Value

Tags: core-data, ios5

I am facing a really weird problem! In my application which is using CoreData, I created a model. When the application ran the database was created. I openend the database using Firefox SqliteManager and added another column to it "ZABOUT" (For some reason the Core Data prefix columns with Z). Anyway, I also populated the ZABOUT column with some data. But now when I retrieve the object from within the app and display the value of ZABOUT it displays null. Any ideas what is going on.

If I set the value from within the iPhone application then it prints out okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data and SQLite are separate technologies, and you can't mix them that way. If you want to add another entity, you need to do it through your Core Data model, not through SQLite.

Core Data configures the sqlite file it uses as a backing store with a private schema that is derived from it's data model. Because the Core Data framework is controlling the schema and contents of the .sqlite file, it's best not to think of it as an sqlite file. The fact that SQLite is used is essentially an implementation detail.

More on [Core data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html), and [what Core Data is Not](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW4). Core Data is not a relational database, and if that's what you're looking for, you might consider just using SQLite directly.  [XMLPerformance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/)  is probably the best sqlite-on-iOS sample.

Comment: So if I have 100 records that I need to insert into SqlLite database which should be available through CoreData what should I do?

Comment: If you're asking how to pre-populate a Core Data store, the short answer is to write a small app to populate a datastore, then copy the datastore it creates into your project <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230354/any-way-to-pre-populate-core-data/>