# How to release an application with preloaded CoreData objects?

Tags: swift, xcode6, osx-yosemite

As I said in title, i want to release an app with preloaded data. The problem is that : I have no idea how to do this in right way.

For the moment, i have in my mind only one though : To save all dates i want to be preloaded, and after that i will  put the .storedata file in application resources folder, and, at first run i will replace the generated .storedata file.

That's how i think to take the location of .storedata file.

```
 let appSupportDir = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.ApplicationSupportDirectory,
            inDomain: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask,
            appropriateForURL: nil,
            create: true,
            error: nil)
        let error = NSErrorPointer()
        let supportDir = appSupportDir?.path
        var  supportDir  = "\((appSupportDir?.path)!)/com.MingleBit.MyAppName/MyAppName.storedata"
        var man = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
  //    var att = man.attributesOfFileSystemForPath(apppp, error: error) // get .storedata file attributes
```

Do you have a better idea to import that data ? 
It's wrong if i will do that as I said above ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have a look to Core Data and preload database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to pre populate core data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230354/any-way-to-pre-populate-core-data)

Answer (score 0):

You have to preload it by using a `xcappdata` file. There is a great tutorial on [this site](http://corporationunknown.com/blog/2014/07/10/preloading-development-data-into-your-ios-app/) which shows step by step, what to do.

Comment: that is for iOS, i must to do this on a mac app, and here i don't have a xcappdata file.

Comment: It's also only for testing and not for general release.