# How to save core data

Tags: ios, database, core-data

I programmatically created core data and programmatically filled it. How do I save this database in project now, so if I give my project to someone, he will get same database without using database creating and filling code?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2230354/3985749) and associated answers.

Comment: Thank you, it really helps. Sorry, i can't accept your answer in comment)

Answer (score 0):

The database saved is only locally. Even an uninstall would clear out all your data.

You either need look for other alternatives, or you can put your create code in an if check, something like this.

```
If(runningAppForTheFirstTime)
{
    //Create your objects in coreData and save them
}
```