# Prepopulate data in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Upto now i was using `sqlite`. I have an app which list a group of products. Each product have product `name`,`sku number`,`price` & `description`.

These are different categories which are main prodcuts,`accessory products` & `add-on products`.

I created 3 tables for these groups in `sqlite`. I can able to fetch data from each table as well. Each table have more than 20000 records/rows of data.

Now I want to use `core data`. I can create 3 entities for these 3 tables,But I cannot enter that much data manually.

**Problem-** How can i populate data in coredata store (sqlite)?

Please help me.

**Note:** Even I have update feature in app that downloads latest db from server and will replace existing db. As I mentioned I sqlite file which I am using currently is different than what core data creates so how can i update coredata sqlite db as well.

Comment: Did you check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230354/any-way-to-pre-populate-core-data

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function which will store your data in core data store. Just execute the function on first launch of your app. You can store a boolean in NSUserDefaults to check if it's first launch or not.

Comment: Hi bisma thanks for your reply. I did that but it's taking so much time. I am fetching data from my existing sqlite db and inserting into coredata generated sqlite DB. It's taking so much time for 25000 records. It causes performance issues.