# Pre-loading data in Core Data, simplest way?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a workout App that uses Core Data with multiple entities and relationships among them. I want to preload Core Data with about 20 workout entries. The simplest way for me would be to use my app to enter those 20 workouts and save them into a file and then reuse this initial file to load the App at first usage. I saw many answers but not using this "simple" setup idea to pre-load data. Can someone give me some advice or share a good link that explains this specific way of preloading data?

Comment: Do you want this data for testing or as default data for app functionality?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2230354/1187415 and the questions linked from there.

Comment: I want it as preset workouts for my app functionality